# Automating the creation of a Django model with `IntegerField()` fields from a list of attribute names

Tags: django-models

I do have a list of attributes (field names) a model should have. This list contains about 170 entries. The field type of all of them will be `IntegerField()`.

I now want to generate a model from this list. So something like:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):

    field_name1 = IntegerField()
    field_name2 = IntegerField()
    ...
```

but automated by code.

For this I tried the following code:

```py
a_list_of_attr_names = ["field1", "field2", "field3"]

MyModel = type("My Model", (models.Model,), {attr_name: models.IntegerField() for attr_name in a_list_of_attr_names})
```

which gave me following error:

```py
  File "D:\Users\Me\Documents\dev\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 105, in __new__
    module = attrs.pop("__module__")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: '__module__'
```

So is there another way to create a model from a list of field names?

---

The background of my question is, that I want to replicate the scheme of the [Bundeslebensmittelschlüssel](https://blsdb.de/assets/uploads/BLS_Variablen_3.02.pdf). Basicly this is a database containing hundreds of food items with their corresponding nutritions, vitamins and so on. The nutritions stored in this database for each food item are listed in the linked table. Each entry in this table has the following fields:

short, description, type, length and unit.

Example for the energy of an food item:

```py
short= "GCAL", description= "Energie (Kilokalorien)", type= "Nu", length= 3, unit= "kcal/100 g"
```

So when I add a new `FoodItem` to my database I want it to have fields for all of the nutritions, and I want to be able to give them values. So as the database sheme of the Bundeslebensmittelschlüssel is more or less fixed I first thought about just adding all the nutritions as `IntegerFileds` to my `FoodItem` model. As I did not want to do it all by hand, I made a list off all the nutritions and asked for the `locals()` method. Also, my list actually is a list of dicts for all nutritions so that I can reference for example the `unit` of an nutrition from my `views` aswell.

```py
[{"id": 4, "short": "GCAL", "description": "Energie (Kilokalorien)", "type": "Nu", "length": 3, "unit": "kcal/100 g"},
    {"id": 5, "short": "GJ", "description": "Energie (Kilojoule)", "type": "Nu", "length": 4, "unit": "kJ/100 g"},]
```

But thinking of it I am not sure if this is the right way to do this. So I also tried to do it all by models.

```py
class FoodItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Nutrition(models.Model):
    short = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    length = models.IntegerField()
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class NutritionDetail(models.Model):
    nutrition = models.ForeignKey(
        Nutrition, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='nutritions_details')
    composition = models.ForeignKey(
        FoodItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='nutritions_details')
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

I created all the nutrition entrys from the Bundeslebensmittelschlüssel as `Nutrition` objects in my database. But then when I create a new `FoodItem`, I need to create a new `NutritionDetail` object for every `Nutrition` object in my database. And if the Bundeslebensmittelschlüssel would change, maybe they drop a nutrition or add alergenes or anything, I can add those entries to my `Nutritions` but I would need to add all new entries to my existing `FoodItem` manually.

And at the moment I am just confused if I would need to create the `NutritionDetails` in my `views.py` or `admin.py` when creating a new `FoodItem` or can I automaticly create `NutritionDetails` for each `Nutrition` in my database in my models throug an `__init__` function in `FoodItem`? Or is the method with the static fields in `FoodItem` the way to go?

I am confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an idea might be to work with:

```
a_list_of_attr_names = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']


class MyModel(models.Model):
    for item in a_list_of_attr_names:
        locals()[item] = models.IntegerField()
```

That being said, if you need to work with a list of field names, you usually do something wrong, and thus likely the modeling is incorrect.

Note that this will *not* change dynamically, so each time you add an item, you will need to make a migration and properly migrate.

Comment: This actually worked. Thank you very much! And you are also right that i am probably doing something wrong. I will rethink my problem and probably report back why I wanted this solution in the first place and if i found another solution.